# query exec fails when trying to write from qt to MS Sql database in windows using ODBC

Tags: mysql, sql-server, qt

I connect to my MSSQL database with odbc and writing data to it. I am not sure why I get the error:

```
QODBCResult::exec: unable to bind variable: “[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented”

bool DataManager::registerClient(Client&)

“INSERT INTO ClientMaster (first_name, mid_name, last_name, phone_number, email_id, address_line1, address_line2, address_line3, dob) VALUES (xxx, xxx , xxx, +xxx-xxx, xx, xx, x, x, 1987-08-30)”

bool DataManager::registerClient(Client&) error “[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented QODBC3: Unable to bind variable”


mDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
mDatabase.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=GLINK_CLIENT_MGMNT;");
mDatabase.setUserName("sa");
mDatabase.setPassword("123456");

if(!mDatabase.open())
```

is my database connection part and below is my query execution part.

```
        QSqlQuery query(mDatabase);

        query.prepare("INSERT INTO ClientMaster (first_name, mid_name, last_name, phone_number, "
                        "email_id, address_line1, address_line2, address_line3, dob) "
                      "VALUES (:first_name, :mid_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email_id, "
                        ":address_line1, :address_line2, :address_line3, :dob)");

        QString phoneNumber = "+";
        phoneNumber.append(client.phoneCode);
        phoneNumber.append("-");
        phoneNumber.append(client.phoneNumber);

        query.bindValue(":first_name", client.firstName);
        query.bindValue(":mid_name", client.midName);
        query.bindValue(":last_name", client.lastName);
        query.bindValue(":phone_number", phoneNumber);
        query.bindValue(":email_id", client.emailId);
        query.bindValue(":address_line1", client.addressLine1);
        query.bindValue(":address_line2", client.addressLine2);
        query.bindValue(":address_line3", client.addressLine3);
        query.bindValue(":dob", client.dob);

        regStatus = query.exec();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue got resolved. I hope the below case is the specific reason for the issue.

I gave date input in the format (`yyyy-MM-dd`), i.e. :

```
query.bindValue(":dob", client.dob.toString(yyyy-MM-dd));
```

I came to know that MSSQL takes date in the particular format only. I am not certain about this, however it works fine now.